# Showing Null Value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select min(code) as AC 
from Tab1e1 
where id=1 
Union 
select min(code) as AC          
from Table2 
where id=1
```

I am getting rows like below

```
ac
--
101
null
```

But I dont want null row. What should I do? Can one help me?

Comment: This can come about because there is no row that matches the condition. SQL will always return a single row if there is no GROUP BY and there are only aggregate functions in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this condition for each where

```
and code is not null
```

like

```
select min(code) as AC from Tab1e1 where id=1 and code is not null 
Union 
select min(code) as AC from Table2 where id=1 and code is not null
```

because **code** value is null

Comment: SELECT MIN(agency) AS agencyCode  FROM Table1 wps  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM Table3 wup  WHERE wup.sym = wps.sym  AND wup.pol = wps.pol                       
AND wup.user_id = 1)                           
UNION 
SELECT  MIN(agency) AS agencyCode
FROM Table2 wps
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM Table3 wup
WHERE wup.sym = wps.sym
AND wup.pol = wps.pol
AND wup.user_id = 1)

Comment: This is my actual query .. please go through and help me

Comment: `select x.agencyCode from (
SELECT MIN(agency) AS agencyCode
  FROM Table1 wps
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM Table3 wup
         WHERE wup.sym = wps.sym
           AND wup.pol = wps.pol
           AND wup.user_id = 1)
UNION
SELECT MIN(agency) AS agencyCode
  FROM Table2 wps
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM Table3 wup
         WHERE wup.sym = wps.sym
           AND wup.pol = wps.pol
           AND wup.user_id = 1)
           ) x where x.agency is not null;`

Comment: Please select Question as DONE if its work, Have a nice day

Comment: Hi Jan, Thank you, have a nice day. From where I have to select questions as done?